# How to capture screenshot for Publish stream using WebRTC in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, webrtc

In WebRTC for IOS,  I am using **RTCCameraPreviewView** to play publish stream and **RTCMTLVideoView** to play remote stream.

I can take the snap shot for Remote steam using the code below:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 2.0f);
 [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
 UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But when I use the same code to capture the snap shot for local stream, I am getting a blank image.

Kindly suggest, how to take a snap shot for the local stream.

Comment: please check following links that can help you answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27646689/snap-shot-is-not-working

for the answer why screenshot is working for a remote stream but not for the local stream is because of video codec.
when you try to capture local stream video's codec is H264, when you get remote steam the video's codec will be VP8 or VP9.

let me know if you need additional help

Comment: @SumitMeena, As my video codec for publish stream is -VP8 only. But it was not working. I have found alternative and its working.

Comment: Good, but as i know the video render for localtrack in ios h264

Answer (score 2):

In webRTC while using **RTCCameraPreviewView** to display the publish stream, you couldn’t take snap shot Because ** RTCCameraPreviewView** handle through **AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer** and its implemented as an OpenGL layer, so you can't use regular CoreGraphic's context to take snapshot over **RTCCameraPreviewView**.
But we can overwrite **RTCCameraPreviewView** **captchaSession** and Set **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput** delegate in our controller and get **Frame** as **CMSampleBufferRef**.
To make it work we need to get “AVCaptureSession” reference from “RTCCameraPreviewView” object.

```
RTCCameraPreviewView *publisherView = [[RTCCameraPreviewView alloc]initWithFrame:self.frame];
       AVCaptureSession *session = publisherView.captureSession;
```

Now we can get list of available ** AVCaptureVideoDataOutput** from ** AVCaptureSession**

```
NSArray *dataOutputList = session.outputs
```

After getting list of dataOutputList filter that array and find correct **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput** on which your publisher video playing.

For example let suppose

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput*captureVideoOutput = dataOutputList[0];
```

that means index ‘0’ has local publisher video **AVCaptureVideoDataOutput**
   Now take reference of old delegates which has set as below

```
id capTchadelegate = captureVideoOutput.sampleBufferDelegate;
```

And then overwrite **AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate** as below

```
[captureVideoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self  queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

After overwrite delegate implement **AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate**
 In your class ab below

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)output didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection;
```

here we will get **CMSampleBufferRef** and convert its to **UIImage**

After getting required **CMSampleBufferRef** image set delegate back for **AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate** so that your publish stream will not stuck for other recipient in same call

```
[captureVideoOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:capTchadelegate queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Answer (score -1):

In Your viewController.swift file

```
func takeScreenshot(_ shouldSave: Bool = true) {
       var screenshotImage :UIImage?
       let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
       let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale)
    self.view.drawHierarchy(in: self.view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
       screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
       if let image = screenshotImage, shouldSave {
           UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
       }
   }
```

Comment: that depend on frame size, not exactly size of buffer image